# I want to append all logs in one file in python

Tags: python

I have code for writing logs on current directory. It is working fine and it writes all logs in one file from different classes.

Now i want to write code in specific directory (ex: Logs directory)

```
class PyLog():

    def create_log_handler(self, module, log_file, log_level=None):

        logger = logging.getLogger(module)
        if not log_level is None:
            logger.setLevel(log_level)
        if not getattr(logger, 'handler_set', None):
            fileh = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
            fh_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s -  %(name)s:%(lineno)d - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
            fileh.setFormatter(fh_format)
            logger.addHandler(fileh)
            if not log_level is None:
                fileh.setLevel(log_level)
            logger.handler_set = True
            setattr(PyLog, 'log_file', log_file)
            setattr(PyLog, 'logger', logger)
        return logger

    def get_logger(self, module, log_file, log_level=None, set_attr=False):


        logger = logging.getLogger(module)

        if not log_level is None:
            logger.setLevel(log_level)

        if not getattr(logger, 'handler_set', None):
            fileh = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
            fh_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s -  %(name)s:%(lineno)d - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
            fileh.setFormatter(fh_format)
            logger.addHandler(fileh)

            if not log_level is None:
                fileh.setLevel(log_level)

            logger.handler_set = True

            if set_attr:
                setattr(PyLog, 'log_file', log_file)
                setattr(PyLog, 'logger', logger)
        return logger

    @staticmethod
    def write_log(logger_method, log_msg):
        log_msg = str(log_msg)
        print ("%s: %s"%(logger_method , log_msg))
        logger_method(log_msg)


    @staticmethod
    def getTimeStamp():
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

I am creating object in some other xyz class like below

```
   try:
       logger = PyLog().get_logger(self.__class__.__name__,
                                     getattr(PyLog, "log_file"), logging.INFO)
   except AttributeError:
       logger = PyLog().get_logger(self.__class__.__name__,
                                     os.path.join(os.getcwd(),
                                                  "%s.log" % self.__class__.__name__),
                                     logging.INFO)
```

Same in some abc class

```
    try:
       logger = PyLog().get_logger(self.__class__.__name__,
                                        getattr(PyLog, "log_file"), logging.INFO)
      except AttributeError:
          logger = PyLog().get_logger(self.__class__.__name__,
                                        os.path.join(os.getcwd(),
                                                     "%s.log" % self.__class__.__name__),
                                        logging.INFO)
```

This use to write logs of xyz class and abc class in xyz logfile in current working directory.

Now i want to write all logs in Logs folder so i changed some line like below but it started writing creating log file for each class like xyz.log, abc.log.

```
       try:
           logger = PyLog().get_logger(self.__class__.__name__,
                                       getattr(PyLog, "log_file"), logging.INFO)
       except AttributeError:
           if not os.path.exists(os.getcwd() + "\\Logs"):
               os.mkdir(os.getcwd() + "\\Logs")

           log_dir = os.getcwd() + "\\Logs"
           logger = PyLog().get_logger(self.__class__.__name__,
                                       os.path.join(log_dir,
                                                    "%s.log" % self.__class__.__name__),
                                       logging.INFO)
```

Please someone help me to fix this. It should write all logs in one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. We have to set set_attr=True then it writes all logs in one file.

get_logger(self, module, log_file, log_level=None, set_attr=True)

Ex:

```
   try:
       logger = PyLog().get_logger(self.__class__.__name__,
                                   getattr(PyLog, "log_file"), logging.INFO)
   except AttributeError:
       if not os.path.exists(os.getcwd() + "\\Logs"):
           os.mkdir(os.getcwd() + "\\Logs")

       log_dir = os.getcwd() + "\\Logs"
       logger = PyLog().get_logger(self.__class__.__name__,
                                   os.path.join(log_dir,
                                                "%s.log" % self.__class__.__name__),
                                   logging.INFO, True)
```